# "adb start-server", Java, Gradle and apache-commons-exec: how to make it right?

Tags: java, gradle, adb, apache-commons-exec

I am running into various problems when trying to run `android start-server` from within Java as external process. The Java is called by Gradle. Let me describe to you what is exactly happening in various scenarios:

**Environment**

- Windows 7 X64
- Java 7
- commons-exec-1.1
- Gradle 1.6
- Android API 17
- IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 Community Edition

**Assumption**
adb daemon is killed and will start up when calling `adb start-server`.

### Case 1

This code:

```java
DefaultExecutor executor = new org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor();
executor.execute(org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine.parse("adb start-server"));
log.info("Checkpoint!");
```

When run from Gradle `run` task of the application plugin, will display the start-server output, i.e.:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

and then it will hang, i.e. "Checkpoint!" will never be logged. Killing the `adb.exe` process manually will cause the code to continue execution.

### Question 1

Why this call blocks? When `adb start-server` command is run from terminal, after a couple of seconds the control is returned to the terminal, so why it doesn't happen in the code?

### Case 2

If instead I use directly the Java runtime like so:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"adb", "start-server"});
log.info("Checkpoint!");
System.exit(0);
```

If calling from Gradle as previously, the "Checkpoint!" will be logged. However, the execution will hang on `System.exit(0)`. Killing `adb.exe` manually will again make Gradle call finish.

In this case no output of `adb start-server` is displayed.

Interesting thing is that when, instead of Gradle, I run the application from IntelliJ IDEA with build setup mimicking that of Gradle's, everything works fine and the application finishes properly.

### Question 2

Why Gradle hangs on `System.exit(0)` and IntelliJ doesn't? Is this somehow related to the fact that Gradle itself is a process that internally calls Java and in case of IntelliJ, Java is called immediately without any indirection? Why does it matter?

### Question 3

Ultimately, I want to be able to run this from Gradle without hangs of any kind. Logging output of `adb start-server` would be a bonus. I would greatly appreciate any hints how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I solved the problem by doing the following:

1. Inside my program, for calling `adb start-server`, I no longer use `org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute("adb start-server")` nor Java's `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb start-server")`.
   Instead, I use `java.lang.ProcessBuilder("adb start-server").inheritIO().start().waitFor()`. Note the `inheritIO()` is added in Java 7 and allows for online reading of the started process stdout, among others.
   **EDIT** The `inheritIO()` in Gradle has no effect when Gradle is called from CLI directly as opposed to being called by IntelliJ IDEA. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671081/windows-java-child-process-doesnt-input-or-output-when-set-to-parents-standard) for details.
   Probably implementing `StreamGobbler` as described [here](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) would fix the problem.
2. In Gradle, instead of Gradle's [application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)'s `run` task, I again use `ProcessBuilder` reusing `run` tasks variables. It looks like so:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
targetCompatibility = '1.7'

// configuration-time of the original run task
run { 
    main = com.example.MainClass; // without this, our custom run will try to run "null"
}

task myRun(dependsOn: build) {

        // execution-time of our custom run task.
        doFirst {

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(tasks['run'].commandLine);
            pb.directory(tasks['run'].workingDir);

            // works when the gradle command is executed from IntelliJ IDEA, has no effect when executed from standalone CLI interface.
            pb.inheritIO(); 

            Process proc = pb.start();
            proc.waitFor();
        }
    }
```

As for the reason of the strange behaviors, I don't have any definite answer, so I refrain from further comments.

**EDIT 9 July 2013**
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931536/how-do-i-launch-a-completely-independent-process-from-a-java-program) seems to point out the answer to Question 2 is: on windows, the parent process waits for child process before it terminates. Unfortunately, the solutions proposed there do not work because of problem stated in Question 1.

Hope this helps,
Konrad

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm answering the wrong question, but if I wanted to start a server from gradle (we're doing  this for tomcat, sonicMQ, ApacheDS, and EnterpriseDB) I would start with the gradle Exec task and only try something else if it was inadequate.

```
task startADB(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'adb', 'start-server'
}
```

Unfortunately I can't answer any of your questions about various bits of code hanging, because I haven't a clue! I just know that if I wanted to launch a server from gradle that's how I'd do it. In fact it's how I am doing it. Another - slightly more complicated - option is to use [the tanuki wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/) or something similar to it. You can still start and stop it from gradle, but you get some advanced features.

Comment: Thanks! I am actually considering starting adb externally to circumvent all the problems I have. Currently I think Gradle hangs because the "run" task of the _application plugin_ has problems with stream buffering [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967932/why-does-process-waitfor-never-return) (I peeked at the source code). Maybe for the same reason commons-exec hangs. I continue the investigation...

Comment: The tanuki wrapper allows you to install basically anything as a service (both in windows and linux) and it may do a better job of starting without hanging. The gradle Exec turns into a simple "net start" or "/etc/init.d/foo start".

Comment: I checked: the Gradle's `Exec` task also hangs on `System.exit(0)`. However, this command works properly:

`new ProcessBuilder("adb", "start-server").inheritIO().start();`

It doesn't hang in any configuration and it displays the output.